# Is this JWT based authentication method safe?

Tags: authentication, authorization, token, jwt

Trying to implement a secure authentication method with JWT for an API which will be consumed for many clients including web (Single Page App), desktop, mobile I've came up with this system:

1. Client calls /auth/login with username and password set
2. After verifying server returns two tokens an auth_token and a refresh_token

   - Auth token is short lived 15 minutes and is used on every following API call
   - Refresh token is long lived maybe a 12 hrs to a week BUT is signed with a secret key in the format user_pass + long_string
3. After the token expires a called to /auth/renew is called

   - The auth token is sent to check how long it's expired (no longer than an hour)
   - The refresh token is sent as well and is validated using the user's password
   - If refresh token isn't expired and the auth token isn't expired for a long time, a new auth token is sent back
   - If the user's password has changed, the refresh token is invalid and the user is required to re-authenticate after their existing short lived auth token has expired

While there is a small window for the auth token  to be expired and still be valid, and there is calls to the database made; is this an overall secure way to authenticate using JWT and to handle password changes and token refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to implement your own authentication infrastructure. Chances you'll get a secure implementation are minimal and now you'll have to maintain all that code also.

Better use a authorization server from a reputable origin, like [Thinktecture IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) or [Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-whatis/) and use standard libraries and protocols.

Some problems I see with your proposal:

1. if you do not sign the access token, what prevents me from changing
   the claims inside?
2. if you need the user's password to validate the refresh token, you must store it in a way that you can retrieve it in clear text. Passwords should only be stored as a salted hash preventing you from getting to the clear text.

Comment: The access token was going to be signed with a separate access key but i see your point in number 2. I completely forget about how the passwords were going to be stored (using bcrypt). Thank you for the answer.